# Create a dynamic Twig_Test with wildcard name

Tags: php, twig

in Twig's documentation it's said "Tests also support dynamic name feature as filters and functions." (filter can be path_* by eg)

But I don't find how to achieve this.

I tried this :

```
new \Twig_SimpleTest('format_*', [$this, 'isFormat'])
```

but I get this error message :

> Unknown "format_web" test. Did you mean "format_*"

when i try to use it in my template.
Anyone know how to create a dynamic test name ?

Thanks

Comment: Which arguments does your method `isFormat` has? Did you forsee the extra `$name`-argument?

Comment: It's like this :
isFormat($name, $arguments)

Comment: Seems the documentation is wrong about this. Tested this and getting the same errors. Perhaps you should open a ticket with `Twig`